# Find Duplicates from two linked tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

1)contacts
2)email_address

All concerned email_address of Contacts are stored in email_address table with its contact id.

I have below query which is giving error

```
SELECT contacts.id  from contacts INNER JOIN 
(select email_address_id from email_address ear 
   group by ear.email_address_id having count(ear.email_address_id) > 1 ) as ed  
   where contacts.deleted=0 AND
   ed.`email_address_id` = email_address.`email_address_id` 
   ORDER BY contacts.date_entered DESC
```

I get the following error

Unknown column 'email_address_id.email_address' in 'where clause
I need help in solving this query

Comment: you should try with using `Having Count()` in your query...

Comment: if you can, paste the field name pls..

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: I get this error Unknown column 'email_address_id.email_address' in 'where clause'

Comment: Try to remove the "`" (apostrophes ). You should either use them for all names or not use them at all. Also, is this the complete statement? Where is closing parenthesis?

Comment: I tried removing "`" but it gives same error : Unknown column 'email_address_id.email_address'  'where clause' . Yes this is the complete statement.All the brackets are properly closed.